# Haskell Illegal term-level use of the type constructor 'Int'

Tags: haskell

I'm very new to Haskell and am trying to multiply a number by itself as followed:

```
Test :: Int -> Int
Test = Int * Int
```

Doing this gave me the following error ' Illegal term-level use of the type constructor ‘Int’'
In the first argument of ‘(*)’, namely ‘Int’
In the expression: Int * Int
In an equation for 'Test': Test = Int * Int

I'm pretty confused from this message. Can anyone explain what went wrong with this implementation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Int` is a type, not a value or expression.

Also note that by convention, tokens starting with an uppercase denote a type, typeclass, or type constructor. For functions, you want to start with a lower case.

```
test :: Int -> Int
test n = n * n
```

If you're in need of a haskell resource, I strongly suggest reading [Learn You a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/). It covers all these basics and more.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error message. In my case, I had a value constructor AssemblyDirective that wrapped a type of the same name, AssemblyDirective. I was trying to use the AssemblyDirective value constructor. I found that the source of the issue was that I forgotten to use the `|` separator between the different type constructors.

This was my code before

```
data AssemblyInstructionOrDirective =
    AssemblyInstruction AssemblyInstruction
    AssemblyDirective AssemblyDirective

data AssemblyInstruction =
    ...

data AssemblyDirective =
    ...
```

That code compiled, but there was only one single data constructor, AssemblyInstruction. The first `AssemblyDirective` on the third line was compiled as another field of the AssemblyInstruction value constructor.

To fix this, I just had to add the `|` delimiter between the different value constructors. Here is what that looked like for me:

```
data AssemblyInstructionOrDirective =
    AssemblyInstruction AssemblyInstruction |
    AssemblyDirective AssemblyDirective

data AssemblyInstruction =
    ...

data AssemblyDirective =
    ...
```